# PowerShell stops processes in background

Tags: powershell, start-process

Did someone notice such a "feature" that PowerShell is not running all the processes in background?

```
foreach ($file in get-childitem *.qvw) {

    write-host $file
    $result = $procs.add($(start-process -filepath $vQlikViewPath -argumentlist "/r","/vErrorMode=0",$file -passthru))

}
```

This should run a process with params. 12 times in a parallel. 
And it does if I'm running it in foreground.

But when I set this up all into a background (as a background task in Windows Scheduler, for example), it is not working. It does starts all 12, but then stops 9-10-11 of them.

---

Simple - when I schedule this in Windows Scheduler as a task and on "General" tab in "Security options" section I check radio "Run only when user is logged on" - it runs smoothly. Runs all processes and throws out all windows in foreground etc. But when I check "Run whether user is logged on or not" - I get as a result that all processes are started in background but most of them are stopped at once.
[WinScheduler screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6PPL.png)

Comment: Technically it can't be in parallel as it's in a foreach.

Comment: I don't know what "can't be" technically, but foreach executes it 12 times in a millisecond and all start and work in parallel. Problem is that when it is started by me from powershell - it runs smoothly all 12 processes. But when it is started in background - it stops some process right after they were started without any cause.

Comment: [off]"Technically" because `foreach` reads each item one by one so "technically" it's not in parallel as all processes are started very fast but not in parallel [/off]. Without any further informations about scheduled task, it would be certainly impossible to fix your problem.

Comment: Simple - when I schedule this in Windows Scheduler as a task and on "General tab" in "Security options" check radio "Run only when user is logged on" - it runs smoothly. Runs all processes and throws out all windows in foreground etc. But when I check "Run whether user is logged on or not" - I get as a result that all processes are started in background but most of them are stopped at once.

Comment: Are you sure they don't need an account or admin rights to be started like `SYSTEM` account within a scheduled task?

Comment: Checked. The account I've done that has highest privileges. And under same account in foreground it runs fine, in background - stops some processes.

Comment: How are you running the script in the Task? What switches are you using.

Comment: Simply - all defaults, Trigger set to daily, Action - Start Program
Program - Powershell
Params - .\script.ps1
Path - path to script.ps1

The only difference between working and not working is a radio that I mentioned in post